# SQL Server XML String Manipluation

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008-r2

Let me state I am an XML novice. That said, my issue is I have a SQL Server that creates XML data, and places that into a file that must pass through a security gate to another server. The gate has a list of several "dirty"words that will cause the files to fail if they are included. What I need, is a way for SQL to search the XML data, every node, and if the "dirty" value is present, strip it out (replace with blank). The XML is not strongly typed, and the "dirty"word could possibly be part of a longer string. In that case, the rest of the string must remain intact.

For example, if the "dirty" word is "hold," the string "We hold these truths to be self evident" would become "We these truths to be self evident."

Again, this "dirty" word could be in any node, and the tags will not always be the same. I need to write a procedure or trigger that analyzes the XML value based on the dirty word list to clean it up.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server? If it's not strongly-typed, is it at least in a column of type `xml`?

Comment: 2008 R2. yes, the column is XML data type

Comment: So, when you say it's not strongly-typed, you mean it has no schema sets associated with it?

Comment: Yeah, pretty much. Sorry if my terminology is wrong. Basically the tags correspond with column names in another database, and it can be any combination of those, from any table. so that's the only real constraint.

Comment: You should look into the [XQuery](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189075.aspx) capability of SQL Server XML columns.

Comment: If `hold` is dirty then what about a part of a word `holdon`, or in quotations `"hold"` or a following period `hold.` or `hold?` or `hold!` or what about `on-hold`? The XML part of this question is not hard. The tricky part is finding the words to remove. So if you could post the code you have to do the string manipulation on regular text data it be would quite easy to change that into working with the XML.

Comment: Mikael, in all those cases, the piece "hold" should be removed, and leave teh rest. i.e. on-hold become on-, etc. On a string, it would be: select @string = REPLACE(@string, 'hold', '') . Just need to translate that into looking at all the XML nodes.

Comment: But, to clarify, it will not just be a single word, but rather any word from a list stored in another table

Comment: Can a word that is to be removed be part of a node name in the XML? Should it in that case  be removed or should it be kept?

Comment: No - a word that is part of the node name should not be removed. That's the main reason i can't just convert the whole thing to a varchar or other string, do a replace, and cast it back to XML.

Comment: Do you have attributes in the XML or are there only elements?

Comment: Pretty sure only elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shred the XML to a table with one row for each node. The table needs an id that corresponds to the position of the node in the shredded XML to be able to write back the changes.

Have your bad words in a table and for each word use `replace` to remove them from the table with the nodes values.

Finally you loop through the cleaned values and write them back to the XML one node at a time for the nodes that was actually modified.

```sql
-- A table to hold the bad words
declare @BadWords table
(
  ID int identity,
  Value nvarchar(10)
)

-- These are the bad ones.
insert into @BadWords values
('one'),
('three'),
('five'),
('hold')

-- XML that needs cleaning
declare @XML xml = '
<root>
  <itemone ID="1one1">1one1</itemone>
  <itemtwo>2two2</itemtwo>
  <items>
    <item>1one1</item>
    <item>2two2</item>
    <item>onetwothreefourfive</item>
  </items>
  <hold>We hold these truths to be self evident</hold>
</root>
'

-- A helper table to hold the values to modify
declare @T table
(
  ID int identity,
  Pos int,
  OldValue nvarchar(max),
  NewValue nvarchar(max),
  Attribute bit
)

-- Get all attributes from the XML
insert into @T(Pos, OldValue, NewValue, Attribute)
select row_number() over(order by T.N),
       T.N.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'),
       T.N.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'),
       1
from @XML.nodes('//@*') as T(N)

-- Get all values from the XML
insert into @T(Pos, OldValue, NewValue, Attribute)
select row_number() over(order by T.N),
       T.N.value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'),
       T.N.value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'),
       0
from @XML.nodes('//*') as T(N)

declare @ID int
declare @Pos int
declare @Value nvarchar(max)
declare @Attribute bit

-- Remove the bad words from @T, one bad word at a time
select @ID = max(ID) from @BadWords
while @ID > 0
begin
  select @Value = Value
  from @BadWords
  where ID = @ID

  update @T
  set NewValue = replace(NewValue, @Value, '')

  set @ID -= 1
end

-- Write the cleaned values back to the XML
select @ID = max(ID) from @T
while @ID > 0
begin
  select @Value = nullif(NewValue, OldValue),
         @Attribute = Attribute,
         @Pos = Pos
  from @T
  where ID = @ID

  print @Attribute

  if @Value is not null
    if @Attribute = 1  
      set @XML.modify('replace value of ((//@*)[sql:variable("@Pos")])[1] 
                       with sql:variable("@Value")')
    else
      set @XML.modify('replace value of ((//*)[sql:variable("@Pos")]/text())[1] 
                           with sql:variable("@Value")')
  set @ID -= 1
end

select @XML
```

Note: In some cases the code above will not deal with values where the modification itself creates the bad value.

```xml
<item>fioneve</item>
```

will be modified to

```xml
<item>five</item>
```

Comment: Mikael, thanks again for this. The data in question does indeed have attributes, not just elements. This seems to work fine for that in testing, but is there anything I should look out for just in case?

Comment: @user1873604 It did not clean the attributes. I have updated the answer with a version that cleans both attribut values and element values.

Comment: Mikael, taking this a step further, now we would like to delete all characters not specified in a predefined list. We discovered that the data could potentially have any Unicode character, and that could take quite a while to compare against all those. So, we want to populate a table with ASCII characters 0-127, and strip out all characters NOT in that list, and keep the XML intact. This would be run in conjunction with the dirty word comparison. So, there are characters that are not allowed, in addition to the words already not allowed. Is this possible? Again, thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Mikael Erikson, I did create a new question; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15978295/shred-sql-server-xml-with-unicode-characters